# Component-only package?

Tags: lightning-web-components, appexchange

I have created a gen 2 lwc package, which includes a component. When I install it, I also get an "app", with it's own main page, logo on the top left, etc. I don't want the app -- I want our component to appear in AppExchange as a component package, without the "app" part. Is this possible? How can I change my package to disable the app>

Answer (score 2):

An app can contain only apex, only LWC, etc. To remove the "app" you should remove the App metadata from your package/repository and generate a new version without it.

Comment: Thanks @renato-oliveira, I've done that (I removed everything from `force-app/main/default/applications/*` -- is that what you meant? But now I get an error whey trying to create the package version: `This package version could not be created because new components were added or existing components were deleted. Add components {CustomApplication=[...]} back into the package version and create the package version again.`

Comment: You should create a new version using the previous as a dependency, if I remember correctly. It seems that you are trying to create a package build for the same version as the one containing the Application metadata. For example, if you generated your app at version 1.0.0-1 (version 1, build 1), then you'll need to generate version 1.1.0-1 now instead of 1.0.0-2 (notice the minor version bump? That this is a new build, but for a different version of your app).

Comment: Thanks. Now I get `Package version cannot be created. Removing metadata components from a second generation managed package is a pilot feature that requires participation in a pilot programme. ` I keep getting the feeling that 2-gen packages are not really ready for prime-time.

Comment: Things like this is why you usually create two different packages, one for testing and breaking things, and another to actually publish things. In your case you might want to delete the package versions that you have already generated and delete the package definition itself, then create a new package with the same name and its new versions.